# What do I need to add to my .htaccess so <? gets recognised as <?php?

Tags: php

It seems my server is not responding to `<?`, and needs `<?php`. How can I make it recognise `<?` as well?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Recommendation is to replace `<?` with `<?php`. With a multi-file search and replace tool that normally is no problem to establish. This will make your code more inter-operable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// On: 
php_flag short_open_tag on 
// Off: 
php_flag short_open_tag off
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped, although it doesn't seem to use it from either .htaccess or php.ini

Answer (score 1):

The `short_open_tag` is what is classified as **PHP_INI_PERDIR** which means that it can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3).  You can't use `ini_set()`.  A `phpinfo()` will tell you whether you are using mod_php5 (in which case you can use the **php_flag** directive or using suEXEC/suPHP/FastCGI in which case you can use php.ini or .user.ini to set this.

However as hakre says, it is better to bet out of the habit of using short tags.